# How to use models in console controllers in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, cron, yii2

I have created contoller file in console folder like :

```
<?php
namespace console\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;
use backend\models\User;

class TestController extends Controller {

    public function actionIndex() {
        echo "cron job  runnning";
        $userDetails = \backend\models\EndUsers::find()->all();

        echo "<pre>";
    print_r($userDetails);
    exit;

   }
}
```

but on running this command from console it throws error like :

```
root@user-desktop:/var/www/html/AWCOX/trunk/source/web# php yii test
cron service runnningException 'yii\base\UnknownClassException' with message 'Unable to find 'backend\models\EndUsers' in file: /var/www/html/AWCOX/trunk/source/web/backend/models/EndUsers.php. Namespace missing?' in var/www/html/AWCOX/trunk/source/web/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php:291

Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: yii\BaseYii::autoload('backend\models\...')
#1
/var/www/html/AWCOX/trunk/source/web/console/controllers/TestController.php(15): spl_autoload_call('backend\models\...')
#2 [internal function]: console\controllers\TestController->actionIndex()
#3 /var/www/html/AWCOX/trunk/source/web/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/html/AWCOX/trunk/source/web/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(154): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#5 /var/www/html/AWCOX/trunk/source/web/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Controller.php(119): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/AWCOX/trunk/source/web/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(454): yii\console\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#7 /var/www/html/AWCOX/trunk/source/web/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(180): yii\base\Module->runAction('test', Array)
#8 /var/www/html/AWCOX/trunk/source/web/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(147): yii\console\Application->runAction('test', Array)
#9 /var/www/html/AWCOX/trunk/source/web/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(375): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))
#10 /var/www/html/AWCOX/trunk/source/web/yii(27): yii\base\Application->run()
#11 {main}
```

So Is there any other way to use/extend application models in TestContoller to run from Console?

Comment: Here you are including `use backend\models\User` this class and you are using `EndUser` class. `EndUser` is exist in your Project ?

Comment: Yes EndUser class is already there in backend/models directory.

Comment: So it's EndUser or EndUsers?

Comment: @Bizley it's EndUsers model need to extended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Yii2, if you want to use models in console than you should create model under `console\models\` and than you can use that model.

I have found this from this website :

http://latcoding.com/2015/08/27/run-controller-yii2-via-console/

Please try this.